# Joules versus newtons

Tags: energy, work, units

What is the difference between a Newton and a Joule?

I know that a Newton is calculated by $F=AM$m but how is that different from a Joule, when a Joule is calculated by $K=1/2MV^2$ or $U= FX$?
I am most likely confusing something simple but I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: They are different units that describe different things (forces versus energy)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research effort.

Comment: Look it up in a textbook or the internet!

Comment: I did and I am still confused or I was a few mouths ago, when I posted the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They describe fundamentally different things.  One describes a force, while the other describes energy.

They are related by the concept of work.  The amount of work done by a force is equal to that force times the distance the force is applied for (well... almost.  If we want to be pedantic, it's the portion of the distance that is parallel to the direction of the force.)

Let's say I am applying a *force* of 8 newtons to a 2kg block over the course of 3 meters.  As you noticed, we can determine the acceleration I cause with that force using $F=ma$ or $a=\frac{F}{m}$.  In this case, I accelerate the block at $4m/s^2$ (note: if you are keeping track of the units, $8N \equiv 8\frac{kg\cdot m}{s^2}$).  However, if I want to talk about energy or work, I would want to use $W=Fd$, where ($W$ is the work done, $F$ is the force applied, and $d$ is the distance).  $W=Fd=8\frac{kg\cdot m}{s^2}\cdot3m = 24\frac{kg\cdot m^2}{s^2}\equiv 24J$.

Now you also noticed that there's another formula which uses energy: $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.  This is a formula for the kinetic energy of a mass traveling at a specified velocity.  If we assume the block that I pushed started at rest (no kinetic energy), and I put 24J of work into it, we know the block will have 24J of kinetic energy at the end.  We can use the above equation for kinetic energy to show that the velocity at the end of my push must be $v=\sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}} = \sqrt{24\frac{m^2}{s^2}} \approx 4.9\frac{m}{s}$

Now, if you knew calculus, you could actually show that, if I accelerated the block at $4\frac{m}{s}$ for $3{m}$ that its velocity would be $ \sqrt{24}\frac{m}{s}$.  However, to do so, I'd have to use calculus and do a lot of extra calculations, which could be complicated if the path I pushed the book along curved.  That's one of the great thing about using energy in calculations -- you don't have to care about the path you took.  You can focus just on the endpoints.

The key here is that energy and force are their own concepts.  A "newton" is not calculated by some formula.  Thinking in those terms will make it harder for you to think about concepts like energy and force in their own right.  Instead, think of "newton" as "a unit of force," and there are equations you can use when you have a force or want a force, such as $F=ma$.  This will be increasingly important as you expand your physics understanding, and we start re-using letters to have different meanings!  If you can capture the concepts, you can use any equation you like.

Comment: Thank you for your very indepth answer it was extremely helpful =)